# How do I set the boundaries for a 'for loop'?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a dataset where I want to plot the data between in a gridbox. The best way to me seemed to be a for loop, but I can't get it to work. My assumption for what the code should be is:

```
for lat in range(53.22010374071,53.46673202514641) & lon in range(1.22201037407, 1.33312034607):
```

It comes up with the error:

```
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
```

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: Is this python? Add relevant tags.

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry for not including that information!

Comment: you can do something like using range(5322010374071,5346673202514641) and then using lat/10000000000000

Comment: You can't just make up syntax. First of all, you need to decide what you want to do. Which values of lat and lon do you want to iterate over?

Comment: Well the plan was to obtain the rows of data where the latitude was between 53.22010374071 and 53.46673202514641, and the longitude between:1.22201037407, 1.33312034607.

Comment: @Eider92 Precisely which values? There are an infinite number of real values between 53.22010374071 and 53.46673202514641. Obviously only a finite number with finite precision arithmetic. But all the same, you need to decide which values you want. Can you do that?

Comment: Whichever ones happen to lie between those two latitudes and also between the two longitudes. Those latlon values are coordinates for a grid square.

Comment: @Eider92 As David said, there are infinite values that "happen to" lie within those bounds. You can't loop over that.

If you wish to check whether a specific list of values lie within those bounds, you should loop over that list instead.

Comment: @Eider92 You are going to need to understand your problem far better than you currently do because you have been incapable of specifying what you want to happen. Step 1 is to understand the problem. Step 2 is to work out how to solve it. You need to get on top of step 1 first because your previous comment betrays a severe lack of understanding.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you are referring to my lack of expertise in Python (I am new to using Python) or not really understanding the error message, I thought it was referring to the format of the numbers in the range not being integers, but I needed to use those exact lat/lon ranges. However, by the use of problem do you mean my understanding of what I want to achieve? That I definitely know. I am looking at temperature profiles, and I wanted to obtain only the temperature profiles within those lat/lon ranges. Now, it has been established that I know my aim (quite clearly) and don't necessarily

Comment: I meant that you did not specify in the question which finite set of values you wanted. You've still not done so.

Comment: fully understand the error, it would have been more useful for you to ask me what I think the error is and what I want from the data instead of telling me that I don't understand anything. I appreciate you trying help, but the answer below seems to have worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build in range() works only for integer looping. Try using for example [numpy linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) :
    import numpy

```
lat_start = 53.22010374071
lat_stop = 53.46673202514641

lon_start = 1.22201037407
lon_stop = 1.33312034607

for lat in numpy.linspace( lat_start, lat_stop, 100 ):
  for lon in numpy.linspace( lon_start, lon_stop, 100 ):
     print "Doing grid at %f %f " % (lat,lon)
```

Gives me output like:

```
Doing grid at 53.441820 1.283738 
Doing grid at 53.441820 1.284860 
Doing grid at 53.441820 1.285983 
Doing grid at 53.441820 1.287105
```

Comment: Is that defining lat_start and lat_stop before the for-loop then? Also, can you then put a for-loop in for lon in that loop?

Comment: I edited the update to contain full code example -- does that help?